# Erro ao pegar imagem do perfil do facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Pessoal estou tentando pegar a imagem do perfil do fb mas retorna o seguinte erro

java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://graph.facebook.com/--Aqui--esta--o--id--/picture?width=150&height=150

Meu código esta assim

```
  Bitmap tempBitmap;
        tempBitmap = Util.getBitmapFromURL(Preference.getUserPhoto(getApplicationContext()));
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap);
        System.out.println("TempBitMap "+ tempBitmap );
        System.out.println("drawable "+ drawable );
        aux.setIcon(drawable);
```

Classe preference metodo getUserPhoto

```
 public static String getUserPhoto(Context c){
    SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
    return prefs.getString("url", "url");
}
```

Minha url eh essa

url: https://graph.facebook.com/IDESTAACQUI/picture?width=150&height=150

Medoto para pegar a photo

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return myBitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Resultado do bitMap e do drawable

TempBitMap null
 drawable android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@22b0eb58

Comment: A foto do perfil que você está tentando obter é privada? (Privacidade da foto está somente eu ou somente amigos que podem visualizar)?

Comment: Não esta como privada, o estranho é que quando eu jogo o link no browser aparece a foto mas no meu codigo quando vou tentar converter para bitmap ele da esse erro

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado usar o `ContentResolver` para obter conteúdo da internet, a forma correta seria utilizar um `URLConnection` ou usando uma bibliotecas de carregamento de imagens, porque elas eliminam código **boilerplate** e tem toda expertise para tratar de cache e redimensionamento de imagem.

Observando o comportamento da url do facebook, ele realiza um redirect para a url real que está atrás de um provável CDN. Para isso, é preciso tratar o redirecionamento manualmente.

Usando o `URLConnection`:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);  //you still need to handle redirect manully.
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

        // normally, 3xx is redirect
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        boolean redirect = false;

        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                redirect = true;
        }

        if (redirect) {
            return getBitmapFromUrl(conn.getHeaderField("Location"));
        }

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Fonte: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Caso use uma biblioteca **third-party**, é bem mais simples:

Usando [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .into(imageView);

// ou
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            // Bitmap disponível
        }
    });
```

Usando [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView);

// ou 

private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {       
        // Usar o bitmap
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed() {
        // Erro
    }
}

Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .into(target);
```

É claro que cada uma delas tem uma forma de configurar cache.

Mas é bom avaliar antes se vale a pena incorporar essas bibliotecas em seu projeto. Se for para um uso pontual, o overhead que ela trás pro tamanho do APK pode não compensar... Ai é bom verificar caso a caso.

Comment: Wakim vlw pela ajuda, usei seu primeiro exemplo HttpURLConnection para não precisar usar libs mas esta retornando null para meu tempBitMap.

Comment: Show, está dando algum erro na requisição que gerou alguma Exception? Pode verificar se teve algum erro no console?

Comment: Vou atualizar minha pergunta com o código que estou usando agora, mas não deu nenhum erro no console porém retorna null

Comment: A url esta descaracterizada? Ao abrir a imagem pelo Browser deu um erro.

Comment: Então essa url que postei eu tirei o id mas se passar o id ela abre a imagem normal no browser

Comment: @roque, pelo que eu entendi, está havendo alguns redirecionamentos ao acessar a url. Para isso tem que tratar isso manualmente. vou atualizar a minha resposta em breve.

Comment: Blz, se for ajudar essa é a url completa  https://graph.facebook.com/806488489468071/picture?width=150&height=150

Comment: Tentei tratar esse redirecionamento mas nao deu muito certo, parece que tem uma criptografia